# Using TCP to communicate between an Android and microcontroller

Tags: java, android, arduino, bufferedreader, tcpclient

I'm attempting to use a TCP connection to communicate between my Android phone and a microcontroller (a Particle Photon, very similar to an Arduino), where the phone is a wireless hotspot not connected to the internet.

Whenever I attempt to get them to connect to one another, I can get the client (Android app) to connect to the server (Photon). The TCPClient helper class seems to get stuck at

```
serverMessage = in.readLine();
```

in the TCPClient helper class. This is my debug result:

```
E/TCP Client: C: Connecting...
E/TCP Client: C: out2 = java.io.OutputStreamWriter@ca4d31b
E/TCP Client: C: out1 = java.io.BufferedWriter@3c624cb8
E/TCP Client: C: out0 = java.io.PrintWriter@378aea91
E/TCP Client: C: Sent.
E/TCP Client: C: Done.
E/TCP Client: C: received = java.io.BufferedReader@36c43df6
E/TCP Client: C: run = true
E/TCP Client: C: I got to the while loop!
```

So it seems pretty clear where the helper class breaks down at in.readLine(). What needs to happen for the code to progress through the line and show the received result?

This is the TCPClient.java:

```
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TCPClient {

        private String serverMessage;
        public static final String SERVERIP = "192.168.43.157"; //your Photon (formerly computer) IP address
        public static final int SERVERPORT = 23;
        private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
        private boolean mRun = false;

        PrintWriter out;
        BufferedWriter out1;
        OutputStreamWriter out2;
        BufferedReader in;

        /**
         *  Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
         */
        public TCPClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
            mMessageListener = listener;
        }

        /**
         * Sends the message entered by client to the server
         * @param message text entered by client
         */
        public void sendMessage(String message){
            if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
                out.println(message);
                out.flush();
            }
        }

        public void stopClient(){
            mRun = false;
        }

        public void run() {

            mRun = true;

            try {
                //here you must put your computer's IP address.
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);

                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

                //create a socket to make the connection with the server
                Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

                try {
                    //send the message to the server
                    out2 = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                    out1 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                    out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
                    Log.e("TCP Client", "C: out2 = " + out2);
                    Log.e("TCP Client", "C: out1 = " + out1);
                    Log.e("TCP Client", "C: out0 = " + out);
                    Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Sent.");

                    Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Done.");

                    //receive the message which the server sends back
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    Log.e("TCP Client", "C: received = " + in);
                    Log.e("TCP Client", "C: run = " + mRun);
                    //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
                    while (mRun) {
                        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: I got to the while loop!");

                        serverMessage = in.readLine();

                        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: serverMessage = " + serverMessage);

                        if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                            //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                            mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                        } else {
                            serverMessage = null;
                        }
                    }

                    Log.e("TCP Client", "C: run = " + mRun);

                    Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

                } finally {
                    //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
                    // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
                    socket.close();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

            }

        }

        //Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
        //class at on asynckTask doInBackground
        public interface OnMessageReceived {
            public void messageReceived(String message);
        }
}
```

For completeness, this is my Photon firmware:

```
SYSTEM_MODE(MANUAL);

TCPServer server = TCPServer(23);
TCPClient client;
int flag = 0;

void setup() {
      WiFi.on();
      WiFi.setCredentials("AndroidAP", "password");
      WiFi.connect();

      // Make sure your Serial Terminal app is closed before powering your device
      Serial.begin(9600);
      // Now open your Serial Terminal, and hit any key to continue!

    // start listening for clients
      server.begin();
}

void loop() {
    if (client.connected()) {
        if(flag == 0) {
            server.write("200");
            // Serial.println("200");
            flag = 0;  
            Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());
          Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
          delay(1000);
        }


        // echo all available bytes back to the client
        while (client.available() > 0) {
          server.write("200");
          Serial.println("200");


        }

    } else {
        // if no client is yet connected, check for a new connection
        client = server.available();
    }
}
```

This is my MainActivity.java:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TCPClient mTcpClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // connect to the server
                new connectTask().execute("message1");
            }
        });
    }

    public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,TCPClient> {

        @Override
        protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message) {

            //we create a TCPClient object and
            mTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {
                @Override
                //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                public void messageReceived(String message) {
                    //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                    publishProgress(message);
                    Log.d("Message", message);
                }
            });
            mTcpClient.run();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            Log.d("values", values[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes along and is looking to do something similar, I eventually got this code to work.

TCPClient.java

```
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

import static android.R.id.message;

public class TCPClient {

        private String serverMessage;
        public static String buttonPushed;
        public static final String SERVERIP = "192.168.43.157"; //your Photon (formerly computer) IP address

        public static final int SERVERPORT = 23;
        private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
        private boolean mRun = false;

        PrintWriter out;
        BufferedWriter out1;
        OutputStreamWriter out2;
        OutputStream out3;
        BufferedReader in;

        /**
         *  Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
         */
        public TCPClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
            mMessageListener = listener;
        }

        /**
         * Sends the message entered by client to the server
         * @param message text entered by client
         */
        public void sendMessage(String message){
            if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
                out.println(message);
                Log.d("TCP Client", "Message: " + message);
                out.flush();
            }
        }

        public void stopClient(){
            mRun = false;
        }

        public void run() {

            mRun = true;

            try {
                //here you must put your computer's IP address.
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);

                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

                //create a socket to make the connection with the server
                Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

                try {
                    //send the message to the server

                    out3 = socket.getOutputStream();
                    out2 = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                    out1 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                    out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
                    Log.e("TCP Client", "C: out3 = " + out3);
                    Log.e("TCP Client", "C: out2 = " + out2);
                    Log.e("TCP Client", "C: out1 = " + out1);
                    Log.e("TCP Client", "C: out0 = " + out);

                    sendMessage(buttonPushed); //this was the key
                    Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Sent.");

                    Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Done.");

                    //receive the message which the server sends back
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    Log.e("TCP Client", "C: received = " + in);
                    Log.e("TCP Client", "C: run = " + mRun);
                    //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
                    while (mRun) {
                        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: I got to the while loop!");

                        serverMessage = in.readLine();

                        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: serverMessage = " + serverMessage);
                        new TCPClient(mMessageListener);
                        stopClient();
                        if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                            //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                            mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                        } else {
                            serverMessage = null;
                        }
                    }

                    Log.e("TCP Client", "C: run = " + mRun);

                    Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);
                } finally {
                    //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
                    // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
                    socket.close();
                    Log.d("TCP Client", "Socket closed.");
                    serverMessage = null;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);
            }

        }

        //Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
        //class at on asynckTask doInBackground
        public interface OnMessageReceived {
            public void messageReceived(String message);
        }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//    private ListView mList;
//    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
//    private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;
    private TCPClient mTcpClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // connect to the server
                TCPClient.buttonPushed = "Get range 1";
                new connectTask().execute("");
            }
        });



    }

    public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,TCPClient> {

        @Override
        protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message) {

            //we create a TCPClient object and
            mTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {
                @Override
                //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                public void messageReceived(String message) {
                    //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                    publishProgress(message);
                    Log.d("Message", message);
                }
            });
            mTcpClient.run();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            Log.d("values", values[0]);
            //in the arrayList we add the messaged received from server
//            arrayList.add(values[0]);
            // notify the adapter that the data set has changed. This means that new message received
            // from server was added to the list
//            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Photon code:

```
SYSTEM_MODE(MANUAL);

TCPServer server = TCPServer(23);
TCPClient client;

void setup() {
      WiFi.on();
      WiFi.setCredentials("AndroidAP", "password");
      WiFi.connect();

      // Make sure your Serial Terminal app is closed before powering your device
      Serial.begin(9600);
      // Now open your Serial Terminal, and hit any key to continue!

    // start listening for clients
      server.begin();
}

void loop() {
    if (client.connected()) {
        // echo all available bytes back to the client
        while (client.available() > 0) {
          server.write("200\n");
          Serial.println("200");
          Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());
          Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

        }

    } else {
        // if no client is yet connected, check for a new connection
        client = server.available();
    }
}
```